# Windows Cmd line sc command with special characters in password

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to run the sc command to change the password of a service.  The password contains special characters and is as follows: **JUdofji37947&%djdubsh27948jdne/33=dffsFSa**.

When running the sc command shown below I am getting a bad password error when trying to start the service.  I have tried with and without quotes to no avail.  Also tried to use a ^ in front of the &.  Any ideas?

```
sc config "NiRoService" password= JUdofji37947&%djdubsh27948jdne/33=dffsFSa
```

Comment: didn't work - the sc command itself failed to execute complaining of syntax.

Comment: tried this already - still getting a logon failure.....i think it's the special characters in the password....trying to escape them with a ^ doesn't seem to do the trick either...

Comment: It's not an escaping problem that I can see. I ran `cdb sc config "NiRoService" password= "JUdofji37947&%djdubsh27948jdne/33=dffsFSa"`, where cdb.exe is the console debugger. I set a breakpoint on `sc!wmain` and evaluated `?? *((wchar_t **)@rdx+4)`. It returned `JUdofji37947&%djdubsh27948jdne/33=dffsFSa`, exactly as passed in, but minus the quotes (the CRT strips them when tokenizing the `argv` array).

Comment: hmmm...this is weird.  are you able to create a local account and set it's password to JUdofji37947&%djdubsh27948jdne/33=dffsFSa and set it to a random service and start up the service to see if it works? I am out of ideas...

Comment: It works. At first I couldn't get it to work, but then I realized the  account I created didn't have the right to logon a service. I have the old ntrights utility, so I ran `ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u serviceuser`. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

For password with '%' try to add another % to escape it.